# Why `static_cast<int>(uint32_t)` works unexpected?

Tags: c++, static-cast, uint32

The following code does what's expected

```
uint32_t a = 1, b = 2;
std::cout << static_cast<int64_t>(a) - b << '\n';
```

Prints `-1`.
But if I change `int64_t` to `int` everything breaks:

```
std::cout << static_cast<int>(a) - b << '\n';
```

Prints `4294967295`.

Does anybody know what's the trick?

Comment: Mixing signed and unsigned types in arithmetic raises red flags in general.

Comment: Both code snippets do what's expected.

Comment: [operator_arithmetic#Conversions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Conversions)